Contact Form in NextJS using Google Workspace
I have an account on google workspace and I'd like to add to my website a contact form. Could anyone gave me a tip how could I do that correctly? I'mthinking of using Google API and Nodemailer but I heard about emails library as well and I'm wondering what will be the best option.
